# Windows 2016 server restart some web sites not restarting

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016

I am having a Win 2016 server restart issue, when it restarts, some hosted sites are not coming back up.  It seems like it is one collection that exist on some IPs while others do restart just fine.  A subsequent restart brings all sites back online.  The sites are started but inaccessible.  Restarting IIS itself does not help nor does cycling the pools.  There is little trace as to what makes it inacessible.

Sites on 2 different IPs are inaccessible but sites on another are accessible. I am puzzling why this is.  Looking at event viewer I see IIS related issues but they don't seem to be stoppers.

```
9010 "The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to access the root history directory 'C:\inetpub\history'.  The directory either doesn't exist or the permissions on it don't allow the history service to access it. The config history feature is disabled for now and will be re-enabled after the issue is resolved. To resolve this issue, please ensure that the directory exists and that the Administrators group have read and write access to it.  The data field contains the error number."
```

This issue does appear to be a troubling issue and I have taken steps to fix it per suggestions.

I also see some DCOM errors related to "D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160" around the time of reset.

I also see some VSS related issues but they don't appear related.

I am using visual SVN which is reporting:

```
AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address x.x.x.135:8445
(OS 10049) The requested address is not valid in its context.
```

This is a likely issue, perhaps there is some sort of port overlap.  For now I have disabled Visual SVN server and will see if that helps.

I guess the thought would be to try to induce a failure at off hours and chip away at what it may be but this is tough on a production server for sure.  Any thoughts?